# Make components required depending on selectOneRadio value

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

JSF2, PrimeFaces 4.0

There is a form with multiple inputFields and a selectOneRadio (and some action button at the end):

```
<p:outputLabel for="R1" value="R1" />
<p:selectOneRadio id="R1" value="#{bean.r1Value}" required="#{bean.r1Condition}" converter="SomeConverter" > 
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.r1PossibleValues}" var="r1Var" itemValue="#{r1Var}" itemLabel="#{r1Var}" />
        <p:ajax process="@form" update="@form"  />
</p:selectOneRadio>

<p:outputLabel for="F1" value="F1" /> 
<p:inputText id="F1" value="#{bean.value1}" required="#{bean.condition1}" />

<p:outputLabel for="F2" value="F2" /> 
<p:inputText id="F2" value="#{bean.value2}" required="#{bean.condition2}" />
```

If user selects first  value of selectOneRadio - field F1 should be required, if second - field F2.
Methods bean.conditionX check the value of radio (and one more condition) and return true/false.

If I select first radio value, field F1 changes to required. Then, if I change my mind select second radio value - I get validation error (that field F1 is required).

If I change:

```
<p:ajax process="@form" update="@form"  />
```

to:

```
<p:ajax update="@form"  />
```

and then:
- enter some values into F1 and F2,
- select a value in radio
-> the values entered into fields F1, F2 disappear.

How can I change set of required fields on selectOneRadio change without losing data and without premature validation errors?

Comment: The scope is View. I believe the problem is that if I don't use 'process="@form"', values entered into fields don't go through Validation and UpdateModelValues phases - so model is not updated. 
However, if I add 'process="@form"' - model is updated and values are saved, but I get unwanted validation as a side effect.

I'm sure there must be an easy why to accomplish what I wan't but I can't figure it out :)

Comment: You are better only updating/rendering partial components not the entire form, re-rendering the form re-sets the values. put a wrapper around your F1 / F2 - then have p:ajax update that wrapper ID (it needs to be a JSF component) - attach a 'rendered' condition on the wrapper! :)

Comment: The problem is I want to change required attribute on fields F1, F2, without losing values entered into those fields. Whether I update the entire form or just the fields doesn't change the described behaviour.

Comment: @perissf - the values in field F1 and F2 were never saved in the bean.  I've just entered them. If I'm not mistaken, I need to process the fields to have the values stored in the bean. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Comment: You are perfectly right, let me cancel my comment. Will post an answer later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `process` attribute to `<p:ajax>` in order to make selectOneRadio trigger a partial Ajax request, that only submits the selectOneRadio itself. Fill the `update` attribute with a space-separated list of the components you need to update, excluding the inputText components, because you want to preserve their values, and their `required` status will be evaluated only when submitting the entire form. Finally, use the `listener` property of `<p:ajax>` for invoking a server method that updates the conditions that make the inputText components required:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="R1" value="#{bean.r1Value}" required="#{bean.r1Condition}" converter="SomeConverter" > 
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.r1PossibleValues}" var="r1Var" itemValue="#{r1Var}" itemLabel="#{r1Var}" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.myListener()}" update="label1 label2" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
<p:outputLabel id="label1" for="F1" value="#{myBean.condition1 ? '*' : ''}" />
<p:inputText id="F1" value="#{bean.value1}" required="#{bean.condition1}" />
<p:outputLabel id="label2" for="F2" value="#{myBean.condition2 ? '*' : ''}" />
```

Where

```
public void myListener() {
    // changes the values of the required conditions based on selected value
    condition1 = true;
    condition2 = false;
}
```

Comment: I've been thinking along the same lines. Problem: the required fields won't be marked as required (with '*') without refresh. Possible workaround: refresh labels only. Another problem: apart from required,  I would like to change "disabled" attribute for some fields in the same way. The workaround will no longer work in this case. I've given up the problem for now (and created two separate forms) but I'm still curious if there's a clean way to solve it.